# Renaming multiple files: mv changing_part_footer.php changed_part_footer.php

Tags: unix, file, renaming

I have files:

```
hallo_flower.php
hallo_house.php
```

I need to rename them to:

```
tjena_flower.php
tjena_house.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for f in *.php; do mv $f `echo $f | sed 's/hallo/tjena/'`; done
```

It assumes you are using a shell like bash.

Comment: Of course. Very nice use of basic unix commands :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if using bash shell, no need to call external command.

```
for f in *.php; do 
  mv "$f" "${f/hallo/tjena}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

On CMD:

```
RENAME hallo_*.php tjena_*.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could command:

```
mv hallo_flower.php tjena_flower.php
mv hallo_house.php tjena_house.php
```